# Why facebook API script does not send like to other person post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey friends I am learning facebook API for my project......and the point where I am stuck is that my script doesn't send like to other person post after takin my access token from database
**Here is my script**

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$host = "localhost";
$username = "a0091119_nalin";
$password = "Hydrogen"; 
$dbname = "a0091119_nalin";
//database connect
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

//Create facebook application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '1604534073172840',
));
$output = '';
//get users and try liking
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT
*
FROM
token_all Order By Rand() Limit 156
");
if($result){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$m = $row['token'];
$facebook->setAccessToken ($m);
$id =$_POST['id'];
try {
$facebook->api("/".$id."/likes", 'POST');
$msg1 = "<font color='get'>Success!</font>";
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
$output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' failed to like.</p>";
$msg2 = "<font color='red'>Failed to Like!</font>";
}
}
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

*I think my concept is right if it is really right then surely I am using wrong **facebook.php** file if yes then suggest me the right **facebook.php** file*

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No @Muhammad Sumon ........this script also doesn't showing any text **like success** or **like fails** but this script redirect the user to like.php file where he choose the post which he want to like

Comment: If you are fetching tokens randomly from your database, then this can hardly be an app that follows Platform Policies. You are not allowed to like stuff in the name of the user just because you have an access token for them - they need to actively trigger each single like.

Comment: @CBroe can you plz show me the script that how I do .........